# How to: call a method every second impleting getchar() or if it's empty then continue

Tags: c, timer, signals, alarm, getchar

So I'm trying to do something like this: I have a function calling another one in which I am reading text line by line from a given file and I want it to execute what it reads(working atm), BUT it should only execute a line once every second so the user has time to write for example an S in stdin, meaning STOP (or something like that), else if the users didn't input anything then the program should continue to iterate the file. How can I do this ?

What I have been using to try this is signal and alarms(), testing out something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>

volatile int breakflag = 2;

void handle(int sig){
    if( getchar()=='a' ){
        printf("it read something from input\n");
        --breakflag;
    }else{
        printf("it didn't read anything from input\n"); 
        --breakflag;
    }
    alarm(2);
}

int main(){
    /*let's say this is part of the method that i call each iteration until I've read EOF.
    now is the part that i should execute whatever i get into the stdin,
    or if it's empty it should continue to next iteration...
    */
    signal(SIGALRM, handle);
    alarm(1);
    while(breakflag){
        sleep(1);
    }
    printf("done\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Sorry for the long description. But I'm having a hard time trying to get anything that works out.
I have found a few answers that helped me throughout this problem but i can't seem to figure it out the way i need it....

Comment: what about a select with timeout ?

Comment: can you give me a quick example of how would I implement that in a program like this? Not quite sure.

Comment: I did, see my answer

Comment: You really can't safely do these kind of operations in a signal handler.  In this case, `getchar()` can block indefinitely waiting for input. And you can't safely make most function calls from a signal handler.  In strictly-conforming C code, [you pretty much can't safely make **any** function calls](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note188): "Thus, a signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions."  Most implementations do provide some functions that are safe to call in a signal handler. Linux has https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html

Comment: Thank you, will keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: it was m first time using signal and alarms also, you know, just a beginner! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `select` with a timeout of 1 sec, for instance :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

int main()
{
  struct timeval tv;
  fd_set fd;
  int i;

  FD_ZERO(&fd);

  for (i = 0; i != 10; ++i) {
    FD_SET(0, &fd);
    tv.tv_sec = 1;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    if (select(0 + 1, &fd, NULL, NULL, &tv) == -1) {
      perror("error on select");
      break;
    }
    if (FD_ISSET(0, &fd)) {
      int c = getchar();

      if (c == EOF) {
        puts("EOF");
        break;
      }
      printf("read char '%c'\n", c);
    }
    else
      puts("nothing to read");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution (under Linux) :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ (sleep 2 ; echo -n a ; sleep 3 ; echo -n z) | ./a.out
nothing to read
nothing to read
read char 'a'
nothing to read
nothing to read
nothing to read
read char 'z'
EOF
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
```

Comment: This seems to make the job for me, I'll try to implement something like this in my project and I'll let you know if it works! Thanks a lot for the fast response btw!